# Anchor tag in url pushes content up past viewport?

Tags: html, css, anchor

https://mcity.umich.edu/contact/#cf

Just discovered this issue and I can't figure out what is causing it. It happens with any hash in the url on any page.

When there's a anchor in the url, the top blue bar goes missing. It seems the whole page is pushed up which makes it seem hidden. Never seen this happen before.

If you check it with dev tools and try pushing the content down with CSS, nothing happens for a few pixels then it corrects itself. Seems like some sort of bug.

Not sure what to do with this one, any ideas?

Comment: If I click the link and then refresh, it shows up again.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb yeah, but it'd still be nice if users didn't have to do that.